# CSS fadein fadeout onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use CSS animations on a div which is shown/hidden using `toggle()`.

I have added `ease-in-out` on my animation but it only fades in and will not fade out.

Here is my css:

```
#form {
display: none;
animation: formFade 2s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: formFade 2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: formFade 2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: formFade 2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes formFade {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes formFade { /* Firefox */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes formFade { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-o-keyframes formFade { /* Opera */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Here is the html/js:

```
<form id="form" >
TEST
</form>

<script>
            $('#formButton').on('click', function() {
            $("#form").toggle();

            });
        </script>
```

It fades in `onclick` but doesn't fade out.  Any ideas why?

Comment: You have just 1 animation that goes from 0 to 1, meaning you don't have the other state. Secondly, you use a jQuery toggle, which is not really achieving anything for you except switching display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `.toggle()` to hide an element just sets it to `display: none` without affecting the opacity. Try this:

```js
$('#formButton').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#form').css('opacity') == 0) $('#form').css('opacity', 1);
    else $('#form').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
#form {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">Test</div>

<a href="#" id="formButton">Click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a very elegant solution.  however my form is large and opacity leaves a huge whitespace.  Is there any way to fix way?

Comment: Really, the easiest way would just be to use jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` functions.

Comment: Yep, although they are jerkier.  Thanks for your solution though it is so much cleaner than my original attempts

Comment: When creating these forms, use display, so when it leaves, it auto prepend to the visible element on site, except it was fixed